# Restrict current from a 9 V battery to avoid blowing a fuse

Tags: current, resistors, fuses

I have an old landline telephone with a 250 V, 250 mA fuse. It will not be connected to a landline, rather, I would like to power it using a 9 V battery (for use as a musical device. I do this with older landline phones that aren't fused and it works fine).

This one has a fuse, I assume, to protect some of the ICs that you wouldn't normally find in old simple phones, but this one had some extra features like memory etc. I've already blown a couple of fuses experimenting.

What is the best approach to regulating or restricting the current on my 9 V battery before introducing it to the fuse? I have been experimenting with resistors, but I can't seem to find any in my pile of junk electronics that make any difference. I know the answer is probably pretty simple (Ohm’s law, dummy), but my brain isn't working right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a 36 ohm resistor in series with the battery. That would limit the short circuit current to 250 ma. However the drop across this resistor in normal operation might affect the performance of the phone depending on the normal operating current of the phone. Do you have a multimeter to measure this current? That would be helpful to know. Otherwise try larger resistors until the phone operates OK. That would not be an ideal solution but it should minimize the blowing of the fuse.

Comment: If it's blowing a 250 mA fuse, it's probably drawing at least 500 mA. I suspect a short circuit or failed component (probably a TVS). Try the 36 ohm resistor **in series** and measure the voltage across it. If the phone input is shorted, you will read almost 9 V on the resistor and close to zero on the phone. If it reads about 1.5 V then there may be a bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 50 Ω SMD resistor, pulled it from another board, put it in series and voila, no blown fuse and phone functions are proper. I had originally started with a 500 Ω resistor and while some functions were working, others seemingly did not have enough power. My other problem was trying to measure resistors before desoldering from a board, which is just silly.